# Hadoop Namenode safemode error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

My environment is hadoop 0.23.5 cluster( three nodes: two for namenode, one for nodemangement & resourcemangement and both three nodes are datanode)

I google all the answers about how to leave namenode safemode and got the same answer :

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

because I run hadoop 0.23.5 on ubuntu 12.10 and it seems that need to be changed to :

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

but I still got the error below...

```
safemode: FileSystem file:/// is not an HDFS file system
```

does anyone knows how's going on?

It would be very appreciated for your time to give me some advice..

Comment: It looks like your instance is set up in standalone mode when you intend for it to be in pseudo-distributed mode.  That, or core-site.xml is not in Hadoop's classpath.

Comment: what do you mean "core-site.xml is not in Hadoop's classpath"?

Comment: If you execute `hadoop classpath` there should be an entry ending with the `conf` directory like `/home/hadoop/bin/../conf`.  Inside that directory is your `core-site.xml` file that defines the URL for your Hadoop instance.  Check that `core-site.xml` file for the correct Filesystem URL.

Comment: okay, I think I know what you said, but I still have questions that what would be the correct Filesystem URL in cluster? when in standalone mode, I just used "localhost:8020" for my Filesystem URL in core-site.xml
but now I have two NameNode, what should I used?

sorry if my question is stupid.. I'm newbie in hadoop..

Comment: For version 0.23.5, [this setup guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.5/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) should help you.

Comment: thanks for your time, it did help.
I have another problem but I think I should create another question to ask.
anyway, thank you very much.